# How to skip duplicate data in foreach loop

Tags: php, woocommerce, foreach

I need help in removing or skipping duplicate data from foreach array, i try to use array_unique() but it doesn't help.

here's my code.

```
<?php
if(is_cart()){
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $term_name = get_the_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat' );

        foreach($term_name as $idterm){
            if($idterm->parent == 0){
                $parentcat = $idterm->description;
            }
            $term_prid = $idterm->term_id;
        }

        $rootId = end( get_ancestors( $term_prid, 'product_cat' ) );

        $root = get_term( $rootId, 'product_cat' );
        if(!empty($root->description)){
            echo '<div class="club-information"><div class="club-record"><p>'.$root->description.'</p></div></div>';
        }
    }
    if(!empty($parentcat)){
        echo '<div class="club-information"><div class="club-record"><p>'.$parentcat.'</p></div></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

if i have more than 2 products of same category in cart it repeat the same data, which should not.

this is what i get from print_r($term_prid)

```
91
91
13
```

How can i get

```
91 
13
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: It's `array_unique()` not `unique_array()`...

Comment: @AlexHowansky it's fixed, could you please help?

Comment: I dont see how you get an array from `$term_prid` when all I see is `$term_prid = $idterm->term_id;` in the loop. That only stores the last `term_id` and makes `$term_prid` a scalar ????

Comment: Is `$term_prid` a string that you're printing multiple times?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I assumed he put `print_r($term_prid);` inside the loop after the assignment.

Comment: @Barmar Well yes, I guess. Trouble is assumptions keep biting me in the .....

Comment: Your logic doesn't make much sense. You're overwriting `$term_prid` and `$parentcat` each time through the `foreach($term_name` loop, so the code after that just gets the last value of each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the IDs you've seen in an array, and check against that.

```
if(is_cart()){
    $seen_ids = [];
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $term_name = get_the_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat' );

        foreach($term_name as $idterm){
            if (in_array($idterm->term_id, $seen_ids)) {
                continue;
            }
            $seen_ids[] = $idterm->term_id;

            if($idterm->parent == 0){
                $parentcat = $idterm->description;
            }

            $term_prid = $idterm->term_id;

        }

        $rootId = end( get_ancestors( $term_prid, 'product_cat' ) );
        $root = get_term( $rootId, 'product_cat' );
        if(!empty($root->description)){
            echo '<div class="club-information"><div class="club-record"><p>'.$root->description.'</p></div></div>';
        }
    }
    if(!empty($parentcat)){
        echo '<div class="club-information"><div class="club-record"><p>'.$parentcat.'</p></div></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: it's still repeating, saving id doesn't help.

Comment: I think you may have found the proverbial "Rabbit Hole" :) Be careful Alice

Comment: Are you running the code shown multiple times? This only removes duplicates within the one loop, not across multiple runs. @Kingtox

Comment: @Barmar did some modification in your code and it worked thanks

Comment: @Barmar your code worked fine that's why i accept it. thanks.